# ¿Como quitar el @ en un input con jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, keypressevent

Necesito que mi `input` (creado en un `form` XML al que no puedo editar) solo reciba números, letras y espacios. Nada más.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
$('input[name="pueba"]').bind('keypress', function(e) {
 var keyCode = (e.which) ? e.which : event.keyCode
  return !(keyCode > 32 && (keyCode < 48 || keyCode > 90) && (keyCode < 97 || keyCode > 122));
});
```

El problema de este código, es que me permite el `@`, la tecla `alt` quisiera deshabilitarla para así no puedan escribir por teclado el arroba.

Será que podrán ayudarme?

Comment: Usa expresiones regulares.

Comment: Aunque podrias bloquear la @ (keycode = 64) aún tendrias más teclas que siguen funcionando, como `:;><?` y seguramente algunas más. Planteate el uso de expresiones regulares u otro tipo de filtro. Ojo con las expresiones regulares si pretendes usar caracteres con tilde, no todas funcionan.

Comment: Por cierto, keyCode está [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode)

Answer (score 0):

Podrías añadir expresiones regulares, en este caso para aceptar solo letras, numeros y espacios, la expresión sería la siguiente:

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9\s]+$/g
```

Un ejemplo de validación:

```
var regexp = new RegExp(/^[A-Za-z0-9\s]+$/g);If(regexp.test(input value){//Match}else{//don't match}
```

Comment: no me queda claro como incorporar eso a mi código.

Comment: Creo que puedes añadirle un atributo a ese input tal que así: $('input[name="prueba"]).attr('pattern' , '/^[A-Za-z0-9\s]+$/g')